# MySQL Find distinct pair of values per group in time interval

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, distinct

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `pv_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_type` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `has_data` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

ALTER TABLE `events`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pv_name`,`time_stamp`), ADD KEY `has_data` (`has_data`,`pv_name`,`time_stamp`);
```

I have been struggling to construct an efficient query to find each `pv_name` that has at least one change in value in a given time interval.

I believe that the query I currently have is inefficient because it finds all of the distinct values in the given time interval for each `pv_name`, instead of stopping as soon as it finds more than one:

```
SELECT events.pv_name
FROM events
WHERE events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999
GROUP BY events.pv_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT JSON_EXTRACT(events.data, '$.value')) > 1;
```

To avoid this I am considering breaking the count and distinct parts into separate steps, since the documentation says that:

> When combining LIMIT row_count with DISTINCT, MySQL stops as soon as
>   it finds row_count unique rows.

Is there an efficient query to find a pair of distinct values for each `pv_name` in a given time interval, that does not have to find all of the distinct values for each `pv_name` in a given time interval?

EDIT @Rick James

I am essentially trying to find a faster non cursor based solution for this:

```
SET @old_sql_mode=@@sql_mode, sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';

DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS check_for_change;
CREATE PROCEDURE check_for_change(IN t0_in bigint(20) unsigned, IN t1_in bigint(20) unsigned)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE current_pv_name VARCHAR(60);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT pv_name FROM events;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = TRUE;

    SET @t0_in := t0_in;
    SET @t1_in := t1_in;


    IF @t0_in > @t1_in THEN
        SET @temp := @t0_in;
        SET @t0_in := @t1_in;
        SET @t1_in := @temp;
    END IF;


    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS has_change;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE has_change (
    pv_name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (pv_name)
    ) ENGINE=Memory DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;


    OPEN cur;

    label1: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO current_pv_name;

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE label1;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO has_change
        SELECT current_pv_name
        FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT JSON_EXTRACT(events.data, '$.value') AS distinct_value
        FROM events
        WHERE events.pv_name = current_pv_name
        AND events.has_data = 1
        AND events.time_stamp > @t0_in AND events.time_stamp < @t1_in
        LIMIT 2 ) AS t
        HAVING COUNT(t.distinct_value) = 2;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;
END //

DELIMITER ;

SET sql_mode=@old_sql_mode;
```

The optimization here is in the application of the limit on the number of distinct values to find for each `pv_name`.

Comment: "distinct pair of values" does not say the same thing to me as "find each that has a change".  Please provide some sample data and sample output.

Comment: If it there is a pair of values that differ in an interval, than the value changed in the interval.

Comment: @RickJames I edited the question. I hope this helps to clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `LIMIT`, so the quote does not apply.  (Or at least, I think not.)

`COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` will, in some cases do a "loose scan", which is better than reading every row.  For example,

```
SELECT name
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT foo) > 3;
```

together with `INDEX(name, foo)` would probably leapfrog through the index to do the `COUNT DISTINCT` of `foos` for each `name`.  Granted, this is not "stopping at 3" as you requested.

You can demonstrate the above by doing

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSIONS STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

To see that it did not (or did) have a Handler_read count that is the size of the table.

The loose scan is not applicable to your particular query for multiple reasons.

Bottom line:  "No, you can't achieve your goal".

Also, the stored routine you wrote will probably be much slower than simply accepting the overhead of a full scan.

Comment: I was saying that if I use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` then adding a `LIMIT` does not help, but if I create a separate query that just uses `DISTINCT`, then I can put a `LIMIT` on that and it will help (per the quote). Then I can run `COUNT` on the result of that. That is what I have essentially done in the stored procedure.

Comment: The relative speeds of the two queries appears to depend on the number of names to iterate through and the size of the time interval. If both are small then the first query I posted is faster and if both are large then the cursor approach is faster, sometimes much much faster.

Comment: As an aside question, are there other ways to improve the cursor based approach, ie parallelization?

Comment: That depends on the distribution of the data.  Is it I/O bound?  If so, then the main objective is to rearrange the data to minimize the amount of data fetched and/or pay other tricks to minimize I/O.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I meant generically for a cursor based query.

Comment: `CURSORs` are generally very slow.